# How is it legal that my college does not have any "co-ed" dorms on campus and they only allow "male-only" and "female-only" dorms?

Tags: discrimination, sex-discrimination, arkansas

I go to a **Private, Christian college in Arkansas**, and I feel as the college should not require students to be separated strictly by gender. I understand visitation rules and such, but I feel like there should be something that says that the college can not forcefully separate males and females in this day and age. I feel as if this type of housing should only be an option for those that request it, or overflow housing for those who are transferring in or did not register in time.

Comment: 5th word: **private** - this means it is not a [tag:state-university] but a private company.

Comment: How does the fact of being private matter?

Comment: @user6726:  The OP used the "state-university" tag originally, which is why it was mentioned.  More broadly, the laws surrounding private undergraduate institutions (and religious institutions, for that matter) are different.  For example, private undergraduate institutions are allowed to be single-sex, but public ones are not.  See [this page from the US Dept. of Education.](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/t9-rel-exempt/index.html)

Comment: You use the phrase "I feel" too much. (Three times in your brief posting.) If you believe something to be unjust and want to make something of it, you should say "This is unjust" rather than "I feel that this is unjust." Your audience may have excellent reason to care whether it's unjust, but no reason to care about your feelings, which are your own business and not theirs.

Comment: Related https://angelusnews.com/news/nation/christian-college-argues-against-co-ed-housing-requirement-in-appellate-court/

Comment: @MichaelHardy There are many people that believe that "this is unjust" has no meaning other than "I feel this is unjust", and saying the latter is more honest. If it does mean something else, it's not clear what it is, or what concern people should have about someone *claiming* that something is unjust, versus them saying that they think it is unjust.

Comment: @Acccumulation : There may be many people who believe that, and there may also be many people who believe the earth is flat. That doesn't make it so. "The latter" can be more honest only in cases in which it is true, i.e. only when the person saying it actually believes that the statement "This is unjust" has no more meaning than that.

Answer (score 6):

Others have mentioned Title IX, the federal law that generally prohibits sex discrimination at federally funded educational institutions, [20 US 1681 et seq](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1681).  However, there is specific permission for single-sex housing in [20 USC 1686](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1686):

> Notwithstanding anything to the contrary contained in this chapter, nothing contained herein shall be construed to prohibit any educational institution receiving funds under this Act, from maintaining separate living facilities for the different sexes.

As to your "in this day and age", this particular section of the law has not been amended since it was first passed in 1972.  If you think it should be, you can certainly write to your members of Congress and tell them so.

However, you say you attend a "Christian" college.  Religious schools get an even broader exemption from Title IX, as Michael Seifert also mentioned.  [20 USC 1681 (a) (3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1681):

> This section shall not apply to an educational institution which is controlled by a religious organization if the application of this subsection would not be consistent with the religious tenets of such organization;

So even if 20 USC 1686 were repealed, if your college determined that mixed-gender housing was "inconsistent with its religious tenets", they would probably be allowed to continue having single-gender housing anyway.

Comment: and atop that: It's a *private* university, they can do stuff a public uni can't.

Comment: @Trish:  True, though not a lot.  As far as I know, the only Title IX exemption that applies specifically to private universities is that they can have gender-based admissions.

Comment: Concerning religious exemptions, there's another way that some religious universities avoid federal regulation:  they choose to [decline federal funding altogether.](https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2016/07/the-controversial-reason-some-religious-colleges-forgo-federal-funding/490253/)  It's conceivable that the OP attends one such institution.

Comment: @Trish: True in general, but Title IX applies to every "education program or activity receiving Federal financial assistance".  That includes practically all private colleges and universities, since the reality is that a great many students rely on federal financial aid to attend college, and private institutions want to able to serve those students (and collect their tuition dollars).  There are some institutions that don't accept such funding, but they are relatively few and obscure.  But it's possible that OP's is one of them; we don't know.

Answer (score 3):

At the federal level, rules surrounding gender discrimination in higher education are controlled by [Title IX](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/tix_dis.html) of the Education Amendments of 1972.  However, [there are certain exemptions](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/t9-rel-exempt/index.html) that have been carved out.

> Title IX generally prohibits a recipient institution from excluding, **separating,** denying benefits to, or otherwise treating students differently on the basis of sex in its educational programs or activities unless expressly authorized to do so under Title IX. Title IX and its implementing regulations contain several exemptions and exceptions from its coverage, including for the membership practices of certain organizations and admissions to private undergraduate colleges.

Of particular relevance to your question,

> Title IX does not apply to an educational institution that is controlled by a religious organization to the extent that application of Title IX would be inconsistent with the religious tenets of the organization.

It is possible that Arkansas state law has more stringent rules concerning gender discrimination in higher education;  individual states may impose additional such rules if they see fit, so long as they don't conflict with federal law.  However, the [Arkansas Civil Rights Act of 1993](http://www.arkleg.state.ar.us/assembly/1993/R/Acts/962.pdf) does not mention education, and the [Title 6 of the Arkansas Code](https://law.justia.com/codes/arkansas/2019/title-6/subtitle-5/), which relates to higher education, does not appear to mention gender.  (Though it's possible I missed it.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clearly known if it is legal. The matter has not been definitively litigated and ruled on by SCOTUS. To paraphrase your question, what legal arguments could you posit in a lawsuit against your college. You would start with this memo on [Executive Order 13988](https://www.hud.gov/sites/dfiles/PA/documents/HUD_Memo_EO13988.pdf), which implements (part of) Biden's understanding of [Bostock v. Clayton County](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/19pdf/17-1618_hfci.pdf). It is uncontroversial that federal discrimination-prohibitions apply to colleges (well-established by case law regarding disabilities). Note that dormitories are listed as an example of a ["dwelling unit"](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-24/subtitle-B/chapter-I/part-100#p-100.201(Dwelling%20unit)).

There is, however, the *potential* for a religious exemption, [24 CFR 100.10](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-24/subtitle-B/chapter-I/part-100/subpart-A/section-100.10), which says

> (a) This part does not:
>
> (1) Prohibit a religious organization, association, or society, or any
> nonprofit institution or organization operated, supervised or
> controlled by or in conjunction with a religious organization,
> association, or society, from limiting the sale, rental or occupancy
> of dwellings which it owns or operates for other than a commercial
> purpose to persons of the same religion, or from giving preference to
> such persons, unless membership in such religion is restricted because
> of race, color, or national origin

In general,

> No person shall be subjected to discrimination because of race, color,
> religion, sex, handicap, familial status, or national origin in the
> sale, rental, or advertising of dwellings, in the provision of
> brokerage services, or in the availability of residential real
> estate-related transactions.

[Subpart B](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-24/subtitle-B/chapter-I/part-100/subpart-B) lists numerous specific prohibitions. Your (apparent) allegation of violation of federal could be thwarted by 24 CFR 100.10. College of the Ozarks filed a related lawsuit, [which was denied](https://adfmedialegalfiles.blob.core.windows.net/files/CollegeOfTheOzarksDistrictCourtOpinion.pdf) but not on the merits.

Comment: I doubt that the practice would be held illegal even in the context of a public university. It would be along the lines of the rare cases such as casting actors and actresses where there is a bona fide occupational qualification, although I don't know the equivalent phrase in this context.

Comment: Gender segregated housing is the predominant practice in all colleges and universities, and was more so when Title IX was adopted. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0743558412447852

Comment: @ohwilleke:  Since about 2001 the [Justice Dept.'s position](https://www.justice.gov/crt/title-ix#2.%C2%A0%C2%A0%20Housing%20(ï%C2%BD§__.405)) is that "under the Title IX common rule, a recipient may not apply different rules or regulations, impose different fees or requirements, or offer different services or benefits related to housing. However, a recipient may provide separate housing on the basis of sex if such housing is both proportionate in quantity to the number of students of each sex applying for the housing and comparable in quality and cost to the student." ...

Comment: It's not clear how the *Bostock* decision affects this (there's a preamble at the top of that page with some convoluted details).  The religious exemption may well still apply, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I think that link is the correct answer to this question, open and shut, without regard to religion or public v. private (which are also an independent reason).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: The authorization of separate housing by sex is actually from the statute, not merely regulation or policy: see the reference to 20 USC 1686 in my answer.  It has been there since 1972.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Though in most university housing today, genders are separated only in the sense that they don't assign people of different genders as roommates sharing a single room (or maybe suite).  OP's school seems to have entire buildings designated for a single gender, which is more unusual these days.

Comment: @NateEldredge:  I did not realize that;  thanks for the correction.  Also, note that [gender-inclusive housing policies,](https://www.campuspride.org/tpc/gender-inclusive-housing/) under which students may elect to share living space with other students of any gender, have become increasingly common over the past 10–15 years.